# Using Angular with Play: Role for Scala Templates?

Tags: angularjs, scala, playframework

When I first looked at Play and went through all the samples, I was pretty excited by the zentasks sample and the fluid, clean, effortless Javascript routing that left the work of rendering things to Play. But we decided instead to go with Angular.

Upon going down that road, I thought that Angular would control all aspects of rendering.

However, we have a page that has to get a socket. We were having the socket made on the server, so for now, we still have a Play (Scala) template doing that. We have pared it down to pretty much nothing: create the socket and then inject it into the Angular context.

But we are also trying to do Protractor tests and that is made uglier by having to figure out how to accommodate the Scala template.

Question: should we just ditch the scala template and have the Angular controller call the server and get the socket? That was my favored approach to begin with.

Answer (score 3):

I'm currently working on two Play apps with Angular and in both we decided to have one single main.scala.html file that load all the necessary controllers,services,directives, etc from angular using of require.js.

The goal with Angular is to create a single page app and therefore you should avoid to mix it with server side templates.

You must see your main.scala.html template as the entry point of your single page application. There you generate and load all the pieces you need and give the hand to angular to manage the rest.

Comment: Yeah I know that stuff, so have you had a case similar to the one I state here? The real question here is are people doing apps where the Angular single page is fetching complex objects like a socket from the server, obviating the need for any server flow control? I would for sure think yes, but I am looking for confirmation or alternate flows along with some rationale.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with Renato.  It's probably better to have a single controller and template that sets up the single page app with angular.  Then use AJAX to send requests from the browser to other controllers (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaJsonRequests).

If want to to avoid Scala templates completely, you can put your web pages and javascript in the public directory and only use AJAX.